# Paypal subscriptions using client side js only

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

Is it possible to create PayPal subscriptions using only a client side javascript (and Firebase if needed)?

I'm a bit confused with PayPal; there are so many frameworks/options to do same thing that I don't know where to look exactly.

https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

This seems similar what I'm looking for except it's only for payments, and I need subscriptions.

Comment: Here's the best answer: ditch PayPal and use Stripe. PayPal has no idea what it's doing, with  50 different APIs and ways to accomplish seemingly nothing.

Comment: @jozenbasin sometimes the choice to use one or another is not related to which has better SDK, sometimes it's strictly related to business and the way they work behind code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an update on this ticket. Paypal do now have a javascript client-side API that works very well. Here is the link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/

Comment: Seems it is not purely client side. Step _6. Verify the transaction_ includes a [server side verification of the transaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#2-server-side). I’m not sure though if it’s possible to just omit this step and whether it would be a secure thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PayPal WPS Subscription Buttons
 https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#recurring-payment-variables

This is a button integration so you can use JS and HTML to create a plan and redirect buyers to paypal.com. You can specify your subscription terms and PayPal will take care of making recurring payments. You can also maintain inventory, profile & loss tracking.

For any API integration its highly risky to use client side JS.

Comment: But it wont provide a callback for successful subscription like in a example that i linked for a payment

Comment: @Aldarund You can use PayPal Instant Payment Notifications: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Comment: but it require a server backend, so it wont work for my case.

Comment: Yes, to use paypal Instant Payment Notifications you need a backend system.

Comment: The variable names a1, p1, t1, a2, p2, t2 for trial periods are too confusing. It seems that the rest api is more clear to understand.